# Zoom & Panning questions (AS3)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, zooming, pan

I'm having a trouble with the Pan gesture in AS3. As I understand, making this:

```
function fl_PanHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    if (escenario.scaleX && escenario.scaleY == 1)
        {
            trace("MAX ZOOM!");
        }
    else
        {
            event.currentTarget.x +=  event.offsetX;
            event.currentTarget.y +=  event.offsetY;
        }
}
```

Okay. Now if I make zoom, the scale will be more than 1 so, I'll be able to pan. But the pan goes outside of the MovieClip I'm zooming.

The project is 500x500, so, I need to Pan only in 500x500 not the white background of flash (project of 500x500 has black background, in a MC, is the MC that is going to be panned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put in some constraints:

```
var target:DisplayObject = event.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
target.x +=  event.offsetX;
target.y +=  event.offsetY;

//if the x or y is greater than 0, that means you can see the left/top edge of the target, so make it go back to 0
if(target.x > 0) target.x = 0;
if(target.y > 0) target.y = 0;

//the stage width less the target width should be negative so long as the target is bigger than the stage.  
//It will get the x point that would make the right edge line up with the stage's right edge.
if(target.x < stage.stageWidth - target.width){
    //so if the x is less than that point (which would make the right edge of target visible), force the x back so the right edges align
    target.x = stage.stageWidth - target.width;
}

if(target.y < stage.stageHeight - target.height){
    target.y = stage.stageHeight - target.height);
}
```